# Is it possible to block dhcp traffic using iptables?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, dhcp, wifi

I have two devices with embedded Linux. One of them (machine A) has two network interfaces: eth that is used to connect machines together and wlan interface to connect to router via WiFi. The second machine (B) has only one eth interface. My goal is to enable access to WiFi networks on machine B. I used some iptables rules to filter packets from machine A to machine B and it works. Now, I need to block dhcp traffic on the first machine so that it does not reach the second machine. I was looking for some iptables rules to do it but I found that it is impossible with iptables. Is there any other way to block that traffic?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Wait, which do you want: Connect the interfaces, or prevent forwarding traffic from one to another?

Comment: @anx I would like to block only dhcp traffic from machine A to machine B, or more precisely between wlan and eth interfaces on machine A.

Comment: This smells like a [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/). When one of the steps you require is to block DHCP, you're probably taking a wrong turn somewhere.

Comment: To remove any ambiguity, can you tell if machine A is configured as an access point or is a simple wireless client? And add in the answer for each device the output of these commands (some will return some results from before but that's still needed)? `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route` then also `ip -br link show type bridge` and  finally `ip -br link show type bridge_slave`.

Comment: @A.B he writes that A connects to a router, which probably means that's the AP...

Comment: "When one of the steps you require is to block DHCP, you're probably taking a wrong turn somewhere." - not necessarily. Rogue DHCP servers are a known issue. Which is why i.e. hyper-v has a mechanism to block vm's from acting as DHCP (unless disabled in the config). IBM once had the issue that people just set up DHCP servers for testing and then parts of the network got those IP's there. Hence filtering makes a LOT of sense, unless you can nail down that no one attaches a rogue DHCP server somewhere.

Comment: @TomTom I *completely* agree with your comment. I was thinking more specifically about the problem as presented here, with a point-to-point-link between two devices... Blocking unknown hosts acting as DHCP is prudent part of network configuration for a network with multiple devices..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I believe this is more or less the setup you envision. A connects to WiFi, and gets a IP address. B is connected to A via ethernet, and have their own (private RFC1918) IPs.

You want B to reach devices on the WiFi.

Now, A uses DHCP to get an IP on the WiFi interface. But it doesn't forward DHCP to different interfaces, unless you run a DHCP proxy. Furthermore, WLAN clients generally can't represent more than one MAC address, so somehow you'd have to assign an extra IP to A - or make A represent B's traffic on the WiFi.

The *easy* way to do this is to make A NAT traffic that's coming from ethernet, and forward it to wifi. This is what your home router does, and will allow B to talk to devices (and internet) on WiFi. Devices on that network will believe the traffic is coming from A, as they can't see B at all.

For how to NAT, see for instance [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/564866/how-to-set-up-linux-server-as-a-router-with-nat).

You should not attempt to clone addresses or any similar silly ideas. IP's are meant to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to block DHCP traffic using successor of the `iptables` - `nftables`. But only in low level table called `netdev filter` which require mentioning full interface name (and that interface must exist). Main chains in that table are `ingress` (weird name for input that used in switches) and `egress` (output)

Some testing:

```
table netdev filter
delete table netdev filter
table netdev filter {
        set We_ask_for_DHCP_server {
                typeof iifname
                timeout 10s
                flags dynamic
        }
        
        set We_just_get_answer_from_DHCP_server {
                typeof iifname
                timeout 10s
                flags dynamic
        }
        
        chain Log_drop_unknown_DHCP_client_searching_for_server {
                limit rate 30/minute burst 10 packets log prefix "[nft.netdev.input.dhcp-not-from-us]: " flags all
                counter drop
        }
        
        chain Check_if_DHCP_answer_was_asked {
                iifname == @We_ask_for_DHCP_server counter jump We_get_answer_from_DHCP_server comment "This is this PC receiving answer from a server"
                limit rate 30/minute burst 10 packets log prefix "[nft.netdev.input.dhcp-not-asked]: " flags all comment "Possibly second rogue DHCP server present"
                counter drop
        }
        
        chain We_asked_DHCP_server {
                delete @We_just_get_answer_from_DHCP_server { oifname }
                update @We_ask_for_DHCP_server { oifname }
                limit rate 30/minute burst 10 packets log prefix "[nft.netdev.output.dhcp]: " flags all
                counter accept comment "This is this PC asking for a server"
        }
        
        chain We_get_answer_from_DHCP_server {
                update @We_just_get_answer_from_DHCP_server { iifname }
                delete @We_ask_for_DHCP_server { iifname }
                limit rate 30/minute burst 10 packets log prefix "[nft.netdev.input.dhcp]: " flags all
                accept
        }

        chain ingress {
                type filter hook ingress devices = { "enp110s0", "wlo1" } priority -500; policy drop;
                udp sport == 68 udp dport == 67 counter jump Log_drop_unknown_DHCP_client_searching_for_server comment "This is some client asking for a server"
                udp sport == 67 udp dport == 68 counter jump Check_if_DHCP_answer_was_asked
                counter accept
        }
    
        chain egress {
                type filter hook egress devices = { "enp110s0", "wlo1" } priority -500; policy drop;
                udp sport == 68 udp dport == 67 counter jump We_asked_DHCP_server
                counter accept
        }
}
```

N.B. Some DHCP servers and clients may support compilation time switch to use regular sockets instead of raw ones - thus enabling use of iptables or non-netdev nftables.