# Ubuntu bridge iptvbox to router

Tags: ubuntu, networking, bridge

I would like to achieve the following configuration but i'm not sure how bridges work

clients

1. iptvbox - generic ip tv box
2. pc1 - runs windows 10
3. pc2 - runs ubuntu server
4. router

network interfaces

1. eth0@pc2
2. eth1@pc2

config

1. eth0@pc2 is linked to router and it should get ip settings via dhcp from the router
2. eth1@pc2 is linked to iptvbox
3. iptvbox should be able to connect to the router trough eth1@pc2 bridged to eth0@pc2 as if it was directly connected to the router
4. eth0@pc2 is required to have an ip address in order for pc2 to be ssh-ed in to from pc1 (both are in the same subnet)

additional info

iptvbox is normally supposed to be linked to the router and is in different subnet from all other clients, the router just routes its traffic to the other subnet somewhere in my IPS network

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Set Up Linux Server As A Router with NAT](https://serverfault.com/questions/564866/how-to-set-up-linux-server-as-a-router-with-nat)

Comment: I dont think I should be using iptables.What I want is layer 2 switching from a bridge interface